# *Temporary* exec format error on Debian/PVE 7.1-10 that went away in seconds

Tags: linux, debian, architecture

I have a script that dumps the current load into a screen window on my server so I can glance without switching to a browser to see zabbix, etc.

The script basically just loops `while ;: do awk "{print $1,$2,$3}" < /proc/loadavg; sleep 20s; done` (but in a fancier output using /usr/bin/rev that makes it easy to read). (Script here https://sizone.org/m/hacks/loadlog )

While running this (on a server with a customer thrashing 18 simul tar backup jobs ..), I got this output:

0113 081430  22.04 22.68 23.82  22.38 22.73 23.82  26.80 23.73 24.12  29.77 24.65 24.42  31.43 25.33 24.65  **/usr/local/bin/loadlog: line 23: /usr/bin/rev: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error** 27.64 25.06 24.58  26.99 25.09 24.60

What can cause a **TEMPORARY exec format error**?

I also did this:

```
$ sudo md5sum `which rev` 1ebd9cc77b09f907767d39d5b4746c4e  /usr/bin/rev
    
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall util-linux
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree... Done Reading state information... Done 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 198 not upgraded. Need to get 0 B/1141 kB of archives. After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used. (Reading database ... 50992 files and directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack .../util-linux_2.36.1-8+deb11u1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking util-linux (2.36.1-8+deb11u1) over (2.36.1-8+deb11u1) ... Setting up util-linux (2.36.1-8+deb11u1) ... fstrim.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it. Processing triggers for mailcap (3.69) ... Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
    
$ sudo md5sum `which rev` 1ebd9cc77b09f907767d39d5b4746c4e  /usr/bin/rev
```

So rev is the same (or md5sum is cleverly hacked to have me believe..). Notably, this is ECC ram on an HP Proliant Gen 9.

What gives? Cosmic ray (vs ECC?)? What do I do to verify things further? Nothing else has given me temporary exec format errors anywhere on the box that I've noticed.

Comment: ECC memory might also create failures. There do exist also other reasons why data in RAM is able to change - hardware failures (especially problems with power supply), software bugs, manipulation.

Comment: Yeah but Error-Correcting ram (and ECC onboard in the Cpu caches) is highly resistant to errors. If this is the cause, I should buy a lottery ticket next.

Comment: Memory errors are more often than you think, even for ECC memory. https://hectronic.se/solutions/development/technologies/memory-storage/ecc-memory-solves-bit-errors/#:~:text=ECC%20Memory%20solves%20inevitable%20bit%20errors%20in%20RAM,to%20faulty%20calculations%2C%20system%20crashes%20or%20unpredictable%20behavior.

Answer (score 0):

A truncated `/usr/bin/rev` file could cause this, but I'm not sure what could cause that to happen.

Some sort of temporary damage to ld.so is another option.

Comment: good point. but was no apt-anything going on during that time. however, checking historical snapshots to see if something changed:


$ md5sum /.zfs/snapshot/202401*/usr/bin/rev | cut -d \  -f1 | uniq -c


     15 1ebd9cc77b09f907767d39d5b4746c4e

nope.

Comment: also, rev wouldnt be truncated during an apt update/install, it'd be atomically replaced methinks.

Comment: that's a good point